# Jquery addclass not working when click li

Tags: jquery, css

i have menu structure like below

```
<ul class="menu_bg" id="menu-main-menu">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-653" id="menu-item-653"><a href="http://apptivowp.apptivo.com/" title="Home">Home</a></li>

  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-650" id="menu-item-650"><a href="http://apptivowp.apptivo.com/artists/" title="Artists">Artists</a></li>

  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-651" id="menu-item-651"><a href="http://apptivowp.apptivo.com/category/show-dates" title="Show dates">Show dates</a></li>

  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-649" id="menu-item-649"><a href="http://apptivowp.apptivo.com/gear/" title="Gear">Gear</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-563" id="menu-item-563"><a href="http://apptivowp.apptivo.com/category/news" title="News">News</a></li>
</ul>
```

i used below jquery for to set a class for when clicking the li.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('ul.menu_bg li a').click(function()
{

   jQuery(this)('ul.menu_bg li').addClass('mymenu');
});
</script>
```

But its not working..the classname mymenu not apllied in for li when i clicked that li.

what is the problem?..

Thanks 
Ravi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to re-do the selector, just:

```
jQuery(this).addClass('mymenu');
```

will add the class the the `a`, and since you want to add it to the `li`, just traverse up the tree first:

```
$(this).closest('li').addClass('mymenu');
```

Comment: It is too!  If you're doing what I said, anyway  :)  Is the page being reloaded?  You probably need to stop the default click event if you're not doing so somewhere else (doesn't look like it).  Change the function to `function(ev)` and add `ev.preventDefault()` inside of it

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#menu-main-menu li a').click(function() {

       $(this).parent().addClass('mymenu');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery(this)('ul.menu_bg li').addClass('mymenu');

The line above is wrong.

use jQuery(this).addClass('mymenu');

Answer (score 0):

As cwolves said you do not need to re-select the item. With `jQuery('ul.menu_bg li).click(...)` you already have selected the *li* tag within your list on Click event.

therefore you can directly use then that element: `jQuery(this).doWhatYouWant`.